# Troubles with VMWare: VM not booting "Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes."

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I'm trying to open a virtual machine with vmware but I'm facing the following problem:

[[image: virtual machine not starting]]

The VM does not start. The other virtual machines I have can be easily opened with vmware.

I don't know how to solve this issue. I've tried the solutions reported here (https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/kali-vm-not-booting-started-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes-4175641200/) but nothing worked.

Can someone please help me? I need to get back all the data and scripts present in the VM.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413527/boot-hangs-at-started-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252603/debian-jessie-boot-hangs-at-started-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes  and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/566919/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391612/boot-stopped-at-started-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes-headless-s based on searching here on U&L